# keep only alphabet characters

Tags: java, regex, string

What method should I follow in java to produce

```
"WordWord"
```

from

```
"Word#$#$% Word 1234"
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use [`String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with the regex `[^A-Za-z]+` like this:

```
String newstr = "Word#$#$% Word 1234".replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "");
// newstr will become WordWord
```

**Edit:** Although OP hasn't mentioned anything about `unicode characters` but since @Joey has made a comment and if at all there a requirement to keep unicode characters then `\\P{L}+` regex should be used like this:

```
String newstr = "Word#$#$% Word λ1234ä, ñ, ж".replaceAll("\\P{L}+", "");
// newstr will become WordWordλäñж
```

Comment: Note that this will throw out things like `ä`, `ñ`, `ж` or `λ`, too, which, depending on who you ask, are letters too.

Comment: @joey: Good point. I have an **edit** section to take care of unicode characters as well.

Comment: You can simplify that to `\P{L}` by the way ;-)

Comment: @anubhava +1 from me.. But what if I want to keep the numbers too?

Comment: @nik686: In that case use: `replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "");`

Comment: @anubhava Thx for the quick response, but with this way I ll miss unicodes :(

Comment: @anubhava It doesn't remove - and ' and also it removes all the . but doesn't remove the very last . Can you help me with that?

Comment: @BugsHappen: `str = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+", "")` will definitely remove anything but unicode letter and numbers from input.

Comment: @anubhava It didn't remove - or ' or last full stop (.). Also it made this string `Th Dursley ha everythin the wanted bu the als ha  secret an thei greates fea wa tha somebod woul discove it`

Comment: @BugsHappen: Provide a demo on ideone.com with your test data so that I can understand it better.

Comment: @anubhava I have done it using my own loop. But thank you very much for your time and energy.. :)

Answer (score 10):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Word#$#$% Word 1234";
    String extract = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
    System.out.println(extract);
}
```

output:

```
WordWord
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a stream:

```
List<Character> letters = string.chars()
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
    .filter(Character::isAlphabetic)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Character.isLetter(char c)` in Character class like this

```
 String s = "Word#$#$% Word 1234";
 StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer();
 for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {
     if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(k)))
        r.append(s.charAt(k));     
 }
 System.out.println("Result " + r.toString());
```

Comment: No upvote for this answer from me.  Please learn to use SO's Markdown wiki formatting.  There's basic help on Markdown on the page when you are entering or editing any question / answer, and links to more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is in more readable form

```
 String inputString = "Word#$#$% Word 1234";
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int k = 0; k < inputString.length(); k++) {


            if (Character.isSpaceChar(inputString.charAt(k))) {
                stringBuffer.append(" ");
            } else {

                if (Character.isLetter(inputString.charAt(k)))
                    stringBuffer.append(inputString.charAt(k));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Output : " + stringBuffer.toString());
    }
```

> **Output** : Word Word