# Linux's strings command for java

Tags: java, linux, string

Is there any tool like Linux's `strings` command for java? I want to see only strings not all printable things.

Comment: I'd argue that a Unicode `String` could contain all printable things.  What are you looking for specifically?  Non-printable characters?  (How would you be able to print those?)

Comment: Do you mean, is there a version/equivalent of Linux/Unix `strings` command, which can display strings from compiled Java class files? If so, please clarify the question a bit.

Comment: @hyde I want to display strings in .class files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows:

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10645087/1717300

Quote from that:

> Someone already wrote a utility that does what you want:
>
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx

Did not readily find a straight out Linux tool for this, but that Question is about doing this in Python, and there's an answer for writing Python tool for the purpose, as well as bunch of linked questions.

Answer (score 2):

strings is a lifesaver. But String.replaceAll() always worked with me,

[keep only alphabet characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872002/keep-only-alphabet-characters)